# Nested Objects Axios Post

Tags: javascript, express, axios

I am trying to have an array of multiple options posted to an array called options from a form with textboxes. However, instead of having multiple options under the parameter options each options keeps overriding by the other.

hooks

```
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [type, setType] = useState("");
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
```

submit function

```
    e.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/new/",
      data: {
      
        title: title,
        description: description,
      
      questions:{
         text: text,
        type: type,
        options: options,
      } 
      
      },
      config: { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } },
    })
      .then(function () {
        alert("Successfully submitted application.");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        alert("Failed to submit application.");
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Options Section in form

```
 <input
            required
            type="options"
            id="options"
            name="options"
            value={options}
            onChange={(e) => setOptions(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="ex. A).Blue"
          />
          <br />
          B:&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input
            required
            type="options"
            id="options"
            name="options"
            value={options}
            onChange={(e) => setOptions(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="ex. B).Red"
          />
          <br />
```

Submit button

```
          variant="primary"
          onClick={(e) => {
            SubmitQuiz(e);
          }}
          type="submit"
        >
          Submit Quiz
        </button>
```

output

```
title   "I"
description "need"
questions   
text    "some"
type    "Select One"
options "help"
```

desired output [image]

Comment: What gets overwritten? From where does the output come?

Answer (score 0):

Use map to create multiple inputs, then set the input name like:

```
i = 0;

name=`options.${i}`
```

Use the increment for this `i` variable.

In your example use like this:

```
<input
    required
    type="options"
    id="options"
    name="options.0"
    value={options}
    onChange={(e) => setOptions(e.target.value)}
    placeholder="ex. A).Blue"
 />
 <br />
 B:&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input
     required
     type="options"
     id="options"
     name="options.1"
     value={options}
     onChange={(e) => setOptions(e.target.value)}
     placeholder="ex. B).Red"
 />
 <br />
```